# Replace days with 1 - 7 R

Tags: r

Hope your doing well, I am working on an assignment related to data pre processing and I need some help in R

I have a column for days in which they are 711 unique values. In total I have 2 million observations. The data has been collected over 2 years and each day represents one day in a week.

For example day 1 is Monday and day 8 is Monday aswell and day 15 Is Monday and so on.

Could someone help me to replace this with 1 to 7 so if day 1 is Monday I want the cell which contains the value 8 to be replaced by 1 and 15 with 1 and so on.

I hope this makes sense.

thank you for your help.

Regards
A

Comment: Use this instead: `date_column = date_column%%7` `%%` is the modulus operator.

Comment: @Vlo, don't forget to take care of sundays

Comment: Hi @akrun, I don't have any text values neither do I wish to replace it with text values. I just want the numbers for e.g. 123456789 10 11 12 13 14 15... to be between 1-7

Comment: More precisely on Vlo's comment: `x = 1:15; (x - 1) %% 7 + 1`

Comment: Sorry, I must have mistaken then.  You could try Vlo's suggestion

Comment: hi @Vlo sorry I am new to R, could you please be more specific? my file is read as mydata and I have many columns within that file, one of them is DAY. How would I write my script?  Sorry to be a pain

Comment: See @alexis_laz's comment. This is the code. `mydata$DAY = (mydata$DAY - 1) %% 7 + 1`

Comment: @Vlo the code above by alexis_laz's has worked.. now the question is how do I replace it within the existing file and write a new file so I can use this file for further analysis?

Comment: Try `write.csv(mydate, file = "mydata.csv)`? Though I don't get why you need to write this file unless you are going to import this new file into another program for analysis.

Comment: it doesn't work, I need to replace the existing column within the data and then assign the function something like mydate <- mydata$DAY = (mydata$DAY - 1) %% 7 + 1

Comment: and then use this write.csv(mydate, file = "mydata.csv)

but when I do mydate<- mydata$DAY.... that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments (since I can't comment), try this:

```
# An example data.frame 
mydata <- data.frame(DAY= 1:21, ABC= letters[1:21])
mydata

# Do "mod 7" with variable DAY, so DAY have now values from 0 to 6,
# Then assign back to variable DAY
mydata$DAY <- mydata$DAY %% 7
mydata

# Replace 0 for 7 in DAY variable
mydata$DAY <- ifelse(mydata$DAY == 0, 7, mydata$DAY)
mydata

# Save final data.frame     
write.csv(mydata, file='mydata.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than issue 7 separate commands (one for each day) you can use dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(day = seq(1:711))

mutate(d, day = day %% 7 +1)
```

What we're doing here is taking the day number and finding its remainder when divided by 7. We have to add 1 back to this so we dont get 0 when there is no remainder.

Comment: Hi @Feargal Ryan how can I replace the new column with the old column within my data file? my data file has 17 columns

Comment: my data file is read as mydata and the column within the file is named DAY

Comment: with your data as a dataframe  `mydata <- mutate(mydata, DAY = DAY %% 7 + 1)`